# order of multiple quantifiers

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

Problem: For a, b, c, d restricted to the universe of positive integers, explain why
∀a ∃b ∀c ∃d   a/b = c/d   is true, but ∀a ∃d ∀c ∃b a/b = c/d    is false.

I understand that the order of quantifiers is significant when there are 2 quantifiers. Here there are 4 and I'm unable to explain why the latter is false.

Is it perhaps that in the former, we are able to choose the proportion (a/b) then duplicate it on the RHS with (c/d)?

Comment: It may be clearer if you cross multiply and make the statements equivalent to multiplication facts rather than division facts.  In any case we can make the first statement true by careful choice of $b$.

Comment: The first statement merely states that we can replicate a proportion with an infinite number of replacememts. The second statement states that multiplcation of two integers can be recreated with an infinite number of replacememt integer multiplications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's just take it slow and re-write them in English. The first statement:

> For all positive integers $a$, there exists a positive integer $b$, such that for all positive integers $c$, there exists a positive integer $d$, such that $$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d} \implies ad = bc$$

First we are given an integer $a$. Given $a$, we want to see if we can choose a $b$ such that the condition holds, because if we can choose such a $b$, such a $b$ must exist.

Take $b=a$. Then for any positive integer $c$, there also exists an integer $d$, namely $c$ itself, such that equation is satisfied. $$ac=ac$$ Thus the first statement is true.

The second statement:

> For all positive integers $a$, there exists a positive integer $d$, such that for all positive integers $c$, there exists a positive integer $b$, such that $$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d} \implies ad = bc$$

First we are given an $a$. In order to show that the second statement is false, we need to show that ***no choice*** of $d$ will work to make the statement true. I.e. the statement must be false for every $d$. So let's show this. At this point, we are now assuming that $a$ and $d$ are given. Now the next part of the statement gives us a $c$ (i.e. we are not free to choose), so now the statement we need to show is *always false* is:

> Given positive integers $a,d,$ and $c$, there (always) exists a positive integers $b$ such that $$ad=bc \implies b=\frac{ad}{c}$$

Now we can clearly see why this is false; not every fraction of the form $\frac{ad}{c}$ reduces to a positive integer, hence cannot equal any choice of positive integer $b$. Therefore there does not always exist a positive integer $b$ such that the condition holds, and thus the statement is false (since it says that there should *always* exist such a $b$).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> $\forall a\exists b\forall c\exists d : a/b=c/d$

*Proof*: Let $a$ any integer. Consider $b=a$. Then, for any $c$, there exists $d$ (namely, $d=c$), such that $a/b=c/d$.

> $\forall a\exists d\forall c\exists b : a/b=c/d$ (false)

*Counterexample*: Let $a=1$. Then for any $d$ there exists some $c$ (for example, $c=2d$) such that the equality $a/b=c/d$ is impossible, since it is actually $1/b=2$.